# When to merge entities by id or object?

Tags: java, spring, entity-framework, hibernate, merge

I'm using `hibernate` in context with springs `CrudRepository`. It has a `save()` method, that basically performs a transactional save or merge, depending on the object. But that should not matter for the core of my question.

When I want to modify an `@Entity` object that comes from *outside* of a `@Transaction`: would it be better to fetch the entity *again* `byId` within a new transaction? Or could I just modify and then merge (save) the existing (detached) entity?

Example:

```
private CrudRepository<Entity> dao;

//find the db object
entity = dao.findOne(id);

//request a DTO via webservice using some of the entity params
dto = api.getDTO(entity.params);

//TODO: merge the response into the entity
updateEntity(entity, dto);
```

Now, the api webservice call cannot be executed within a wide spanning transaction, as it may be long running. Thus I'm having a detached entity here that I want to merge.

I could now use one of the following approaches:

```
//now merge the dto
@Transactional
public void updateEntity(entity, dto) {
    entity.param1 = dto.param1;
    entity.param2 = dto.param2;
    dao.save(entity);
}
```

Or I could fetch the entity first:

```
@Transactional
public void updateEntity(id, dto) {
    entity = dao.findOne(id);
    entity.param1 = dto.param1;
    entity.param2 = dto.param2;
    //save(entity) can be neglected as the entity was fetched within the tx
}
```

Both may work, but the question is: which approach should be the preferred way, depending on the situation?

Where do I see benefits of the DIY Merge (2nd approach): if we first fetch the entity fresh inside the transaction, we cannot get `LazyLoadingException` during the merge, if any child objects are accessed.

Also I think a `em.merge(obj)` will at first always trigger a "select by id" to the database to find the entity that should be merged to. If I'm correct here, we could as well always fetch the entity within the transactional manually, as we don't get a performance gain or anything when favoring merge. Correct?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: If so, it would be anyways interesting who prefers which approach for a reason.

Comment: Since your updateEntity don't really know how "fresh" your entity would be, I'd prefer to fetch the entity in updateEntity. But as said it's a matter of opinion, from my limited experience, it's how I've seen it done.